# .htc-файлы не срабатывают в ие

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Для скругления уголков блока в ие7,8 подключаю файл ie-css3.htc

```
article #news-box{
        background: url(/images/news-backg.png) no-repeat center top;
        position: relative;
        width: 267px;
        margin: 3px 20px 0 0;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
        border-top: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
        border-left: 2px solid #a8a8a8;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Для Firefox 3 */
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Для Safari 4 и Chrome */
        -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
        behavior: url(css/ie-css3.htc); /*Для IE*/
    }
```

но он не срабатывает. Подскажите, как можно это исправить либо какой-нибудь альтернативный способ решения этой задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Адрес картинки для фона задан от корня, а .htc файла - относительный.

Comment: В таком виде behavior: url(/css/ie-css3.htc); тоже не срабатывает.

Comment: > Note: this path is relative to the HTML file being viewed, not the CSS file it is called from.[Пруф.](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/) В общем, как сказал @ZekMan - путь "относительный", но относительный того файла, который просматривается, а не относительно CSS-файла. Кстати, я параллельно подключал и JS-версию. Плюс ко всему, для Apache не помешает добавить строку в htaccess:    AddType text/x-component .htc

Comment: я что-то не могу понять, какой тогда путь прописать надо. за js версию спасибо, попрубую и её подключить.